# python pandas: how to add a value to specific rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv where one column is a six or seven digit ID number. I want to add the number 0 to the beginning of all the IDs that have six digits. How is this possible?

for example

```
id

203434
405679
1049294
139294
1037912
```

I would like it to be

```
id

0203434
0405679
1049294
0139294
1037912
```

any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to convert the series dtype to string first, because integral values do not start with leading zeroes. Once you have a string you can use the [Series.str.zfill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) method to add leading zeroes.

Try the following:

```
df["id"] = df["id"].astype("string").str.zfill(7)
```

The 7 will ensure that your id values are zero-padded on the left up to 7 characters.